# Перетягиваемые View

Tags: xcode, ios, objective-c, graphics

Задача стоит следующим образом: на одном view располагается четыре одинаковых по форме и размеру прямоугольника. Необходимо написать форму для теста где три из них условно содержат ответы на вопрос и должны перетягиваться в четвертый, в зависимости от выбранного ответа будет варьироваться дальнейшее поведение).

Вопрос:
Каким образом можно реализовать подобное поведение без движков? Можно ли также без OpenGL, Core Animation-Core Graphics?

Буду благодарен за любые конструктивные предложения!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Тыц!](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=drag)

Comment: Не первый раз выручаете добрым советом, большое спасибо!